# including my Cookie page on my home

Tags: php, cookies, include, html

my problem is simple : I have a cookie check page (cookies_check.php) that I want to be included on my home page (accueil.php).

So I've made this on accueil.php (and it's for now the only code in this page):

```
<?php include ('Controleur/cookies_check.php'); ?>
```

And here's cookie_check.php :

```
    <?php
if(isset($_COOKIE['pseudo_TP_espace_membre']) 
    AND !empty($_COOKIE['pseudo_TP_espace_membre'])
    AND isset($_COOKIE['co_auto_TP_espace_membre'])
    AND $_COOKIE['co_auto_TP_espace_membre'] == 1
    )
    {
        include_once('../Modele/connexion_sql.php');// connexion à la bdd

        $req = $bdd->prepare('SELECT id, pseudo, pass FROM membres WHERE pseudo = :pseudo AND pass = :pass');
        $req->execute(array(
            'pseudo' => $_COOKIE['pseudo_TP_espace_membre'],
            'pass' => $_COOKIE['pass_TP_espace_membre'],
            ));
        $resultat = $req->fetch();

        if($resultat)
            {
                session_start();
                $_SESSION['pseudo'] = $_COOKIE['pseudo_TP_espace_membre'];
                $_SESSION['id'] = $resultat['id'];
                echo $_SESSION['pseudo']; // permet de tester que tout à fonctionné, et sera retiré dans la version finale              
            }
    }
?>
```

But if my cookie page works well, and shows some result (as $_SESSION['pseudo'] in the end), there's nothing on my home page, like the link does'nt work.

And if I delete everything on cookies_check.php and put something like `echo 'hello';`, it works...hello appears on accueil.php.

And if I copy the content of cookie_check.php on accueil.php and open it, it works as well.

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php require_once('./Controleur/cookies_check.php'); ?>
```

Please use this way or

```
<?php include('./Controleur/cookies_check.php'); ?>
```

Please check the file permission to access the file .

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately, none of these solutions is working. What do you mean by "check the file permission"? Where can I do that?

Comment: Means ,Please confirm that you have rights to access the the file.

`try{
 if( !file_exists("Controleur/cookies_check.php") )
 {  throw new Exception("Unable to include resources");  }
 else{  require_once("Controleur/cookies_check.php");  }
}catch(Exception $e){
 echo $e->getMessage();
 exit;
}`

please try this also.Please also verify the file name is correct.